# How to add users in keycloak using RESTFul API with POSTMAN?

Tags: java, jwt, auth0, keycloak, jaas

I want to use [`keycloak`](https://www.keycloak.org/) as a broker server for Identity and Access Management and I don't want to use login screen provided in keycloak as I have different clients like Android, IOS and web application using the same backend server.

I wan't to know if it is possible to create user, accept terms and conditions, send two factor authentication using SMS, have custom fields in login like adding adress using a POSTMAN/ RESTFul API. I know keycloak have provided [API guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html) but they have not included anything about accepting terms and conditions, adding SMS based validations.

Following would be an opinion based question but, if these features are not available in keycloak, what are the other identify broakers I can use and it should be open source with capability to use my own database.

Edit:
I have checked [auth0.com](http://auth0.com/), okta/ stormpath but they are not open source and for custom database like in auth0 its requires enterprise edition.

Comment: that is a web flow. if you are using api. it's your responsibility to present the terms and only create the user if they "accept". looks like you just post to [this endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html#_create_a_new_user) with a valid user object and it'll create

Comment: thanks @mavriksc for answering, can you suggest something for two factor authentication using SMS, I saw there is an github which everyone is referring to, https://github.com/nickpack/keycloak-sms-authenticator-sns, but it does not work for me. For this custom flow how to add a RESTful call?

Comment: For the SMS authenticator part, you should post another question with the tried configuration and the errors/result you get.

Comment: I agree with your comment @XtremeBiker as for now I am going through the code of keycloak and will customize the core code to provide SMS authenticator along with email.